# Valid form - display just 1 error always [angular]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I valid my form using patterns / required on all inputs like below:

```
<div class="crazy-error" ng-show="myFrom.email.$dirty && myFrom.email.$invalid">
  <span ng-show="myFrom.email.$error.required">INVALID: Required</span>
  <span ng-show="myFrom.email.$error.pattern">INVALID: Pattern</span>
</div>
```

This code works cool for me however I want to display just on error all the time so if i have 3 inputs:

- name
- email
- color

And for example all 3 are filled incorrectly display error just from first invalid always.

It's obvious it can be done with something like code below for each error display div:

```
<div class="crazy-error" ng-show="myFrom.email.$dirty && myFrom.email.$invalid && (myForm.name.$valid || myForm.color.$valid)">
```

But this looks a bit messy and as soon as form grow up and will have for example 7 inputs logic become really too complicated.

Is there some nice way to always display just first error instead of all of them?

Answer (score 0):

you could use ng-hide -https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide  and ng-if - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf  directives to make the conditions simple.

Comment: Hey jonny, can you provide some example please? I can be wrong But I feel like `ng-hide="value"` is the same as `ng-show="!value"`, at another hand `ng-if` result is same as well just other way to do it (ng-if append to DOM, ng-show, ng-hide just set css property)